# test website with internet explorer 7

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-7

Is there a program or website that can show me what my website will look like in Internet Explorer? I know there's one out there, I just can't find it.

EDIT:Preferably a program.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://browsershots.org/

Allows you to test several versions of all the major browsers, including MSIE.

Comment: +1 Wow i didn't know this one, thanks for sharing. It's really nice and useful.

Comment: This tool is nice for basic stuff, but unfortunately it doesn't let you login or test ajaxy stuff or any of the more advanced functionality.

Comment: when you get to that site, you can run this code in the browser to remove all of the extra browsers from being selected very quickly: `jQuery('input').attr('checked','');`

Answer (score 21):

[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) should do. Also for Internet Explorer 6.0 and 5.5. The latest version has added support for running on Windows 7, although it says it's still somewhat unstable.

If you only need to test IE7, IE8 does a decent job at that. Press F12 and select IE7 from the Browser Mode dropdown.

Comment: Actually the support Windows 7 been added in last version (version 0.3.5)

Comment: Fixed, and updated the URL as well. Wasn't exactly the page I had intended, but typing the full URL on my phone was a pain as it was :)

Comment: IETester is not a true test. It uses a variety of ie dll's and is a real mixed bag and crashes often. Far better to use the vhd's available on msdn

Comment: Didn't crash for me when I needed it, but it seems somewhat system dependent. I think it's nice to be able to do most of your testing without Virtual PC. To be sure, you could use virtualization to verify you're still on the right track every now and then.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Windows you can always run Windows with IE as a virtual machine on your PC.
You need to install [MS Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (it's free) and then download one of the [IE App Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) (also free). There are images with IE6, IE7 and IE8 installed.
The images have some time limit, but Microsoft keeps updating the files, so you can always download an image which will be valid for some months.

Comment: from experience, IE VPC images are always more reliable than IETester

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 8 :)

in developer tools you can set the browser.

Or online [crossbrowsertesting.com](http://crossbrowsertesting.com) you can check this site.

Answer (score 4):

**[browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/start?cbsid=browserlab)** and **[saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/)**. Both have a free trial for commercial use, and you saucelabs is free if you agree to only use it for open source projects.

Comment: Didn't know about browser lab! This just helped me a lot. Thanks man!

Comment: Shame its shut down now :-(

Answer (score 4):

Try [Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx):

"We built SuperPreview to simplify the process of testing and debugging layout issues across different web browsers and platforms. You can view your pages in multiple browsers simultaneously or view how a page renders in a browser and compare it to a comp or mock-up image of a page."

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer (up to version 10): Just press F12, to get the webdev tools. In there you have a bar and that contains compability views, IE7 upto current version.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like MS have since upped their game on this one. http://www.modern.ie now provides VM downloads for a wide range of OS and IE version combinations, all for free. One of the options is for IE7 with Vista.

I'm currently running IE10 on Windows 8 via virtualbox on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see your site on old versions of IE is that:
If you have IE9+, open your current version of InternetExplorer, press F12, click on "Browser Mode" tab, then choose the version you want.

see screenshot here:
[image]

Works better than IE-tester, and easier than using virtual machine.

Comment: I mean I only asked this question 5 YEARS AGO but sure go ahead and add your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can run IE 7 under WINE with [these instructions](http://www.wine-reviews.net/wine-reviews/applications/ie-7-on-linux-with-wine.html). If you aren't on Linux you can use VirtualBox to create a Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Is running IE7 under WINE on Linux a good indication? Can you really be sure it will behave exactly the same as in Windows?

Comment: @Kobi: No. But then again, that's true with any of these testers that _aren't the actual program_.

Answer (score 0):

[Browserpool](http://browserpool.de/kc/wob/portal.jsp) has a free service where you can access a number different OS/Browser versions via VNC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use official virtualisation tools from Microsoft (free). They provide free versions of Windows (VMs) with certain IEs installed.

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

I usually install IE Debug Toolbar (http://www.debugbar.com/) and Companion.JS (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage) additionally on each VM.